# Android development Room SQL query

Tags: sql, kotlin, android-room

I want to add an item into a table,but if the item already exists in the table,i wanna modify a column,this is my Dao

```
@Dao
interface BasketDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun upsert(item: BasketItem)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(item: BasketItem)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM basket_items")
    fun loadBasketItems(): LiveData<List<BasketItem>>
}
```

I already have a conflict strategy for the upsert function,to replace the item if it exists,but i want to only modify the value of a column if the item exists,not replace the entire item,what can i do

Comment: Can u show an example of this?

Comment: If i have an item with the name "item1" in the database table,when i add another item with the name "item1" i want the column "quantity" from item1 to increase by 1

Comment: Show you BasketItem entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using two database calls (one to query existing item and second to insert/replace the item).

In Dao:

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM basket_items WHERE name = :name")
suspend fun getItemByName(name: String): BasketItem?
```

Then in you data layer:

```kotlin
val newItemToSave = //
val existingItem = basketDao.getItemByName(newItemToSave.name)
if(existingItem == null)
    basketDao.upsert(newItemToSave)
else
    basketDao.upsert(existingItem.copy(quantity = existingItem.quantity + 1)
```

Comment: If i use "WHERE item_name = name) it doesnt know who the function's parameter name is but if i use :name,it does,why is that happening? what do the ":" represent?

Comment: And if this function works,you just solved my problem,i'll try to implement it in an hour or so and i'll get back to accept your answer

Comment: ":" just represents that the next word represents a function parameter, otherwise it will just consider it a normal string

Comment: But can i pass a BasketItem as a function parameter and modifi the querry to search for the item itself,or do i need to specify a column from that item,like an atribute such as name,price,quantity or any other column that items in that table have

Comment: The query that is written is an sql query so we cannot pass the entire object. To find a particular item, the best way it to pass a primary key which uniquely identifies the item.

Comment: Ty man,it worked,if i have any further questions related to android development in general,could i feel free to contact you?

Comment: You can post them here on Stack Overflow. You will definitely get a quick response from someone (including me)